# What is the quickest way to find whether the eigenvalues of a $2 \times 2$ matrix are inside the unit circle?

Tags: matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

The most direct way is to simply calculate the eigenvalues.

However, is there an easier way?

I know that $\lambda’_1 \lambda_2=D$ and $\lambda_1+ \lambda_2 =T$. Can we use this somehow?

Comment: You may use the so-called *Gershgorin circle theorem*, see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gershgorin_circle_theorem

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, the criterion is that $2 > 1+D > |T|$.

(Not too difficult to show directly from the quadratic formula $\lambda_{1,2}=\frac12 (T \pm \sqrt{T^2-4D})$.)

Comment: Could you explain how you get it from the equation? I don't  see it immediately.

Comment: Well, I never said it was *immediate*, you have to compute a little! ;-) The roots lie symmetrically in the complex plane with respect to the point $T/2$, either right/left if $T^2-4D \ge 0$ or above/below if $T^2-4D < 0$. So you consider those cases separately. But to begin with, the point $T/2$ has to lie on the line segment between the points $-1$ and $+1$, so you have $|T|<2$ as a necessary criterion directly.

Comment: Are you sure the criterion is not: $|T|<1+D$, and $|D|<1$? i.e. the **absolute** value of the determinant must be smaller than one?

Comment: From the inequality $0 \le |T|<1+D$ it follows automatically that $D>-1$, so it doesn't have to be stated explicitly.

Answer (score 1):

In general the Gershgorin Theorem is a good way to locate the eigenvalues within circles on the complex plane.

The center of those circles are the diagonal values and the radii are the sum of absolute values of non-diagonal terms on each row or each column.

For example for $\begin {pmatrix} 3&5\\2&1\end {pmatrix}$ eigenvalues are within circles centered at $3$ and $1$ with radii of $5$ and $2$ respectfully.